# Countdown start on button press

Tags: php, javascript, html, countdown

Ive got an problem. I have an button that sends an command to an perl script. For 60 seconds the page will just load and load. So i need an countdown to tell the user how much time until the perl script is finished. So i got his javascript from the web that automaticly counts down when the page loads. Is it possible to reverse this?

http://goo.gl/cYdKg

Comment: how about not making them wait, and push it in to the background and alert them when its done

Answer (score 1):

You see what happens, when you don't state your requirements correctly? Two people doing the same wrong thing (bad for us, we did not clarified before, tho).

```
$.fn.timedDisable = function(time, callback) {
    if (time == null) {
        time = 5000;
    }
    var seconds = Math.ceil(time / 1000);
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var disabledElem = $(this);
        var originalText = this.innerHTML;
        disabledElem.text( originalText + ' (' + seconds + ')');
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            disabledElem.text( originalText + ' (' + --seconds + ')');
            if (seconds === 0) {
                disabledElem.removeAttr('disabled')
                    .text(originalText);
                clearInterval(interval);

                if (typeof callback !== 'undefined')
                    callback();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#btnContinue').click(function() {
        $(this).timedDisable(5000, function() {
            window.alert('done');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I want it to load the button as normal, and when i press it, it gets disabled and starts the countdown from 60 seconds. I want to reverse this: http://goo.gl/cYdKg

Comment: Well that kinda worked the way i wanted it to. But when i clicked to button it does not send the command to the perl script. :S

Comment: ok, I'm not writing you that. even this one, you could've easily transformed yourself. please refer to jquery ajax() call documentation...